# Adding link to your facebook app in photo post message

Tags: facebook-graph-api

[image]

Can anyone tell me how this facebook application was able to make 'MemeGen' a link in this post?  I have a photo upload application, and everything works great, but I can't figure out how to stick a link like this in the posts.

This is the markup that they managed to get into the message.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=302156236502659" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/application.php?id=302156236502659" aria-owns="ukp31lp1" aria-controls="ukp31lp1" aria-haspopup="true" id="js_4">MemeGen</a>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

That is obviously not a normal photo upload, but an Open Graph action, which publishes a user generated image – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#usergenerated

(And at that, it is in violation of the rules, because actions are only supposed to post real photos that the user publishing the action took at that very moment with his camera – and I doubt that this particular image with text on it qualifies as such.)